# Why can't open a link from field type - string > url

Tags: url, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a custom string field with url pattern, after I populate the field with my link (a link to a Pdf file on my local pc)

I try to open it from my entity form and it doesn't work. The link is valid: I checked it on my local computer and I use it as attachment on a crm email entity and it opens with no prob. But when I try to open my PDF from the field that holds the link on my entity form it doesn't work.

Am I missing something? are there special rules for string field with URL pattern? Does saving a string path in that kind of field mixs/breaks the path?

Comment: Share some sample url & any error message you are seeing?

Comment: Did you assign the url format option to this text field?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen well after checking it again I found that to my path was added http:// - automatically, my file is local and not a link to a website.. how can I change/fix it ? or should I choose a different type of field ?

Comment: @Damkulul: text fields cannot display navigable file paths. When the URL format option is specified only http:// and https:// schemes are valid.

Comment: What did you expect to happen for users who don't have this file stored locally? CRM is a browser-based application so all URLs must be online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text fields cannot display navigable file paths. When the URL format option is specified only http:// and https:// schemes are valid.

An alternative could be to create a custom HTML web resource and design a custom UI control allowing navigation to or download of files.

Answer (score 0):

To have clickable links you need to create the text field accordingly.

[image]